# Pointer to char, different terminologies

Tags: c, arrays, string, language-lawyer

I used `strncat` several times, but just now check its formal definition in the standard:

```
#include <string.h>
char *strncat(char * restrict s1,
     const char * restrict s2,
     size_t n);
```

> The strncat function appends not more than n characters (a null character and characters that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by s2 to the end of the string pointed to by s1. The initial character of s2 overwrites the null character at the end of s1. A terminating null character is always appended to the result.

Normally I would think of `s1` and `s2` simply as pointers to char. But as seen, the standard calls them differently:

- the string pointed to by `s1`
- the array pointed to by `s2`

The only difference between `s1` and `s2` is a const qualifier - is that why one is called an **array** and the other called a **string**?

Moreover, in the footnote:

> Thus, the maximum number of characters that can end up in the array pointed to by s1 is strlen(s1)+n+1.

So here they refer to `s1` differently: an array (not a string) pointed by `s1`

Is there any implication of these different ways of calling `s1` and `s2`?

Comment: a string is also an array (of characters and null-terminated), an array is generally not a string

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *The only difference between s1 and s2 is a const qualifier*

No, not necessarily.

- The destination array, `s1` **must** be already null-terminated. So, it can be safely called a *string*.

  Quoting `C11`, chapter  §7.1.1/p1, *Definitions of terms*

  > A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
  >   character. [...]
- However, for the source array `s2`, null-termination is **not a must**, in case, given size `n` is less than the actual length of the array. So, it *must* not be a *string*, always.

So, **TL;DR** - The *destination* array will be a *string* always (hence can be used interchangeably) but there's no such guarantee for the source array.

---

Also, just to highlight the *diference* in the usage, let's compare this with the description of `strcat()`, which has a similar syntax, minus the size. So, there, both the arguments needs to be null-terminated as there is no other means for the function to determine the end of the *source* array `s2`. Thus, notice the wordings there (*emphasis mine*), from chapter §7.24.3.1

> The `strcat` function appends a copy of the **string pointed to by `s2`** (including the
>   terminating null character) to the end of the **string pointed to by `s1`**. The initial character
>   of `s2` overwrites the null character at the end of `s1`. If copying takes place between
>   objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Here, both the arrays **must** be strings, and hence, the usage.

Answer (score 4):

In C, a **string** is `NUL`-terminated, where an **array** is not (necessarily). That's why this function takes the `n` parameter; because `s2` is not necessarily `NUL`-terminated.

Comment: You probably meant `NUL` not `NULL`, didn't you? `'\0'` is `NUL`  is `0` is null-character. `NULL` is something different.

Comment: strictly speaking it's null character (differentiate with NULL pointer)

Comment: @alk Yes, my phone auto-corrected my `NUL`s without me realizing it.

Answer (score 2):

An *array* is a region of storage.  A *string* is a particular sequence of characters (ending in a null terminator) that can be stored in an array.

An array of `char` may or may not contain a string at any particular time.

(I am posting despite there being several answers already, because the other answers don't make the container-contained relationship clear).

With the `strncat` function, the first argument must point to a character in an array that contains a string (we say "point to a string" for short); but since the second argument may be length-counted, it can point to a character in an array that does not contain a string.